# i do dua after ruku in witr do i go back into ruku after the dua and complete the salah as normal? or after the dua do you go into sujood?

Tags: salat, witr

salam

i've read hadiths which are different to the way i usually pray witr. i have tried to find answers to my question but i haven't been able too.

say i'm praying 3 rakah witr. one after the other without sitting in the 2nd.
**in the 3rd rakah after ruku i do dua. do i go back into ruku, stand, sujood and finish the salah or straight into sujood after the dua and finish? please help**

jazakallah

Comment: This needs some clarification: First why don't you perform tashahhud in the 2nd? And Secondly what are you referring to by du'a? Is it qunoot? Thirdly we don't know what you are talking about if you don't share the information that you refer to, how others perform witr or what have you read? How do you perform witr?

Comment: i used to pray 3 rakah with tashahhud in the 2nd and takbir in the 3rd after surah and then dua but i read a hadith which said 'don't perform witr like maghrib' not qunoot but different duas from the quran.
and hadith ‘Aishah (may Allah be pleased with her) who said: The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) used not to say the tasleem in the (first) two rak’ahs of Witr. According to another version: “He used to pray Witr with three rak'ahs and he did not sit except in the last of them.” (Narrated by al-Nasai, 3/234; al-Bayhaqi, 3/31. al-Nawawi

Comment: aying the tasleem after two rak'ahs, then praying one rak’ah on its own, because of the report narrated from Ibn ‘Umar (may Allah be pleased with him), that he used to separate the two rak'ahs from the single rak'ah with a tasleem, and he said that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) used to do that. (Narrated by Ibn Hibban (2435); Ibn Hajar said in al-Fath (2/482): its isnad is qawi (strong).)